# Does my choice of pg_dump format impact restore speed?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

According to the docs for my version of Postgres (8.4.2), pg_dump can "output in script or archive file formats."  The script-formatted dump (4GB) takes 1.5 hours to restore, and I'm wondering if the archive format is any faster.

My script-formatted dump is using COPY commands, by the way, so it's not like I'm doing one insert at a time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Archive format has small impact on restore time.

That's because actually, when you restore from plain format, it is equivalent to:

```
cat backup.file | psql emptydb
```

and when you restore from "compressed" format, it is equivalent to:

```
pg_restore backup.file | psql emptydb
```

, and the cost of decompression with pg_restore is usually negligible, compared to write-intensive COPY/CREATE INDEX commands which happen during restore.

For large dumps, restoring from compressed dumps may be a bit faster (less disk reads).

It might be even faster with `-j` (`--jobs`) option. It can be used only with "compressed" format, and it allows paralell restore with N concurrent jobs (sessions).

For more details about `-j` option, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pgrestore.html. Example:

```
pg_restore -j 4 -d emptydb backup.file
```

Comment: Using `pg_restore -j 2` decreased my restore time from 90 minutes to 45 minutes!  I'll try `-j 4` next.  Thanks!

Comment: In simple terms -j x allows you to throw x processes at the problem allowing you to use more CPU power / cores to restore.  Eventually you'll overwhelm your IO subsystem and then the restore will start to get slower.  On machines with fast IO subsystems it's well worth experimenting with.